# The first Stiefel-Whitney class of a trivial line bundle $E=M \times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes, line-bundles, non-orientable-surfaces

If the base space $M$ is non-orientable, is the trivial line bundle $E=M \times \mathbb{R}$ also non-orientable? i.e. $w_1(E) \neq 0$. If so, how could it be proved? Could we use $w_k(\xi\times\eta)=\sum_{i=0}^k w_i(\xi)\times w_{k-i}(\eta)$?

(update due to the answer)
If the base space is a mobius, all fibers are perpendicular to the base space, like a 'thick mobius'. Is this fiber bundle a line bundle? Is this fiber bundle non-orientable? If so, how could I calculate its first Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1 \neq 0$?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trivial vector bundle over any manifold has $w = 0$. The *tangent bundle* $TM$ of a nonorientable (smooth) manifold $M$ has $w(TM)\not = 0$, but that doesn't apply to arbitrary bundles over $M$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it is clear.

Comment: Hi anomaly, the answer inspired me to have some more questions (updated in the description): If the base space is a mobius, all fibers are perpendicular to the base space, like a 'thick mobius'. Is this fiber bundle a line bundle? Is this fiber bundle non-orientable? If so, how could I calculate its first Stiefel-Whitney class w1≠0?

Comment: If I'm understanding your diagram correctly, you're looking at the normal bundle of the (thickened) Moebius strip in $\mathbb{R}^3$. It should be a nontrivial bundle (as a trivialization of it would more or less just an orientation of the base space), and $H^1$ of the base space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a small group.

Comment: Hi anomaly, thank you for the reply. Yes I suppose it is the normal bundle of the mobius strip. I read one answer that says: If a manifold $M$ is non-orientable , the normal bundle of the manifold must be non-orientable as well. Is it true？ It might be good to open this question through another link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439226/normal-bundle-of-a-non-orientable-manifold.    You are more than welcomed to answer if you are interested in this question.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Proposition 2 on page 38 of [this](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/milnstas.pdf), it is an immediate consequence of the axioms defining characteristic classes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it helped me.